# How can I update the latest image that my docker service/stack uses?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack, portainer

In the `.yml` definition, I'm always pulling the `latest` image of my service.

When I push a new image to the registry and I want to update the image that the service in my stack uses. I don't see any `--pull` flag, and the documentation for [docker service update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/) doesn't explicitly mentions this.

How can I re-deploy using the recently pushed `latest` image?

Comment: First suggestion would be not to use `:latest`. Honestly, the more I use Docker, the more problems I see which are caused by the use of this tag.

Comment: We don't have a robust CI setup yet to auto-tag and stuff, so for the time being our CI can only do `:latest`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *really* shouldn't use `latest` in production or anything beyond local machine testing/learning. It makes everything ambiguous as to which image you're using, and you can't tell in `docker service ls/ps` if it's current by default and all sorts of other ambiguities (like SHA's not being visible in Docker Hub's GUI).

If you have no way around it, at least Swarm *tries* to query your registry and check for an updated SHA. If it sees one with `docker service update --image <username>/<repo> <servicename>` then it will pull and do a rolling update. You can watch `docker events` to be sure things are happening, and you can use `docker service ps --no-trunc <servicename>` to check afterward and see the SHA hashes of old and new images.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  The environment is not prod, it's just a temp integration environment until devops team gets ownership

Comment: So basically just run `docker service update` with `--image` flag, right?

Comment: For your information, the latest version of Portainer (1.18.0) gives you the abiliy to update a service via a click and to force a new image digest resolution (that'll update the image associated to a service).

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a compose file to deploy a service.  I would not recommend using this command:

```
docker service update --image <username>/<repo> <servicename>
```

This causes your file to be out of date and no longer the source of record for your service configuration.  Instead, update your compose file with the specific image version, as Bret Fisher suggested, and run this command:

```
docker stack deploy -c </path/to/compose.yml> <servicename>
```

Keeping valid records is important if other people are also managing the swarm.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I did the update and there was a hot minute where the old container was down and the new one wasn't up yet. I only have one replica but I expected the new container to come up before the old one shutdown. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to have more than one replica?

Comment: I would try a "start-first" order under the 'update-config' section of compose.    https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config

Answer (score 6):

To add to *Bret Fisher*'s answer, running `docker stack deploy -c compose-file.yml` with the same `compose-file.yml` file, and having an image tagged as `latest` will indeed compare the SHA of the images and redeploy the corresponding service's image if needed.

This is thanks to the `--resolve-image` flag added in Docker 17.09, which default to `always`.

And while testing it, I found out that it would even pull the newest image if needed too.

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30951#issuecomment-342647614.